# Pytorch parallel functional calls for multiple locations in a tensor

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Does anyone know if there is a function in PyTorch that allows you to call a particular function for all the locations in a tensor where a condition is satisfied?
For example, for all the locations in a tensor where the value is equal to 100, a function has to be called without using any for loops. I want to modify other tensors for these locations. I know I can just get the list of locations and then call the function for each location but I want to avoid that. Thank you for your help.
Something like torch.where(a==100,function1())

Adding more details after the request in the comments:

```
function1(x,y): #(x,y) are co-ordinates
    ... some code based on (x,y)...
    a[x,y] = 20
    b[x,y] = 10
```

Let's assume we have 2 2D(single row) tensors a = [1 2 100 100 5 6 200 8 2] and b=[3 4 5 5 6 10 3 8 9].
Now I want to pass the coordinates of where a == 100  in our case (0,2) and (0,3) to function1 and modify the values of a and b at those locations. I hope this helps.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more with a minimal working example?

Comment: Thank you for trying, I may have found what I was looking for. I'll post it here after some time.

Comment: I was not successful, @osbm I have added more details. I hope it helps. Thank you!